# Selection disabled while using HTML5 Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, html

Using HTML5 Drag and Drop, text within the draggable container becomes non-selectable.

I've tried adding user-select CSS tags to the parent element of the text but it did not seem to help.

```
   [draggable] {
     -moz-user-select: all;
     -khtml-user-select: all;
     -webkit-user-select: all;
      user-select: all;
   }
```

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6sRe8/) (from HTML5 Rocks) demonstrates the issue I'm having.

The [HTML5 Rocks Drag and Drop tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/) does say "If you want to enable other types of content to be draggable, you'll need to leverage the HTML5 DnD APIs."  I guess I don't know how that can work

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6uXx8/) works, but makes use of jQuery UI, I cannot use jQuery UI due to its heavy payload.

Is there a standard, lightweight way to get selection with drag and drop support?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/6sRe8/1/
please let me know i it works for you, i will explain in answer

Comment: It did work!  So it looks like there isn't a way around it but that changing the draggable element to a smaller item is the trick.

Comment: yes, how you imaginate select and drag on same element ? it is only one physical action (drag by mouse)

Comment: I see, I suppose that makes sense when you put it like that.  I guess I was getting the handler element confused with the column itself.  Thanks!

Comment: @eicto, good solution, also `event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(element, 0, 0)` can be added to your code, it help to set "full" element as a "drag image"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So simple trick here is to make dragable header  element, not whole element.

```
<div class="dragme">
    <header dragable="true">Header</header>
 <p>Content</p>
</div>
```